# A few questions about creating a minimum closure with functional dependencies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

So I have the following functional dependencies:

```
S -> T
V -> SC
SD -> P
SD -> V
```

Now what I would think to do is separate out the FDs so that there is only one element on the right side of all of them:

```
S -> T
V -> C
V -> S
SD -> P
SD -> V
```

Next I would find the closure of each element on the left:

```
S+ = S, T
V+ = V, C, S, T
SD+ = P, V, C, S, T
```

Now the part I find confusing is how I would go about reducing the redundancies and getting a minimal closure? Which ones can I get rid of with this information?